# How to take periodic pg_basebackup without losing any WAL files. How to pause wal archive

Tags: postgresql, docker, database-backups, wal

Environment: PostgreSQL 13.x Docker container.

I took a pg_basebackup and have configured PostgreSQL 13.x with wal_archive=on. And it is working as expected.

I see that it is recommended to take pg_basebackup periodically. How can I rotate the base_backups weekly or daily?

Example: If new `pg_basebackup` is running every Saturday night, Should we consider stopping/pausing wal_archiving for that duration?

```
#Locations:
pg_basebackup : /db-backup/basebackup
archive_command: /db-backup/wal_files
```

So want to move archive `db-backup` every Saturday.

```
mv /db-backup /db-backup-old
```

While performing these Should I pause the `wal_archiving` process? As per docs
we can stop/pause it by setting [24.3.1. Setting up WAL archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/continuous-archiving.html)

```
archive_command = ''
```

Is this the right approach? If so, should we reload the configuration OR any way we can update this configuration on-the-fly?
Note: using Postgres-docker container.

What I am trying to achieve is:

If some data is getting written on DB during DB backup rotation, either it should be in new basebackup OR new wal-files directory.

Please correct me if these confusions are irrelevant.

Comment: This doesn't seem very workable.  Some WAL files will be needed to do PITR by two backups, so there is not a clear division of WALs into which backend they "belong" to.

Comment: @jjanes But once we take a Basebackup, we require the WAL files from that point of time only. Afaik, Previous WALs are not required.

Comment: As per docs
[Making a Base Backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#:~:text=To%20make%20use,recover%20your%20data.)


```
To make use of the backup, you will need to keep all the WAL segment files generated during and after the file system backup. To aid you in doing this, the base backup process creates a backup history file that is immediately stored into the WAL archive area. This file is named after the first WAL segment file that you need for the file system backup.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) with next options:

```
pg_basebackup --checkpoint=fast --format=tar --wal-method=stream -D "$BACKUP_DIR/$FNAME.bak"
```

Where `--checkpoint=fast` sets checkpoint mode to fast (immediate). So all transactions will be flushed to disk

and `--wal-method=stream` will stream write-ahead log data while the backup is being taken. This method will open a second connection to the server and **start streaming the write-ahead log in parallel while running the backup**. Therefore, it will require two replication connections not just one. As long as the client can keep up with the write-ahead log data, using **this method requires no extra write-ahead logs to be saved on the source server**.

Answer (score 0):

What I have worked out till now is.

```
 1. Create basebackup which getting saved to /backup_location/basebackups/
 2. Create /backup_location/basebackups/wal-`date`
 3. cp -r /postgres/wal_archive_location/*  /backup_location/basebackups/wal-`date`/
```

This will causing keeping some duplicate WAL files. (Like today's backup and tomorrow's backup might have same WAL files as we used `cp` command.

But no data will be lost. And this works.